# Get the average of each N groups

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, average

I saw some people here have kind the same problem that I have now... but nothing has helped me with :/

I've a table Test with 2 columns. A date and an integer value.
And I need the average every N records.
For instance

```
Date        | Info
2013-01-01  |  210
2013-01-02  |  213
2013-01-03  |  214
2013-01-05  |  197
2013-01-06  |  192
```

....

And let's supose that N = 3

I need to populate a table with

```
Averages
212.3333 (that's the average of the 3 first Info's) (210+213+214)/3
208.0000 (213+214+197)/3
201.0000 (214+197+192)/3
```

I have tried this

```
delimiter $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS calcAvg$$
CREATE PROCEDURE calcAvg()
begin

DECLARE v_finished INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
declare v_avg DECIMAL default 0.0;
DECLARE initial_date date;

DEClARE cr CURSOR FOR 
    select avg(i) from  (
        select t.info i
           from test t
          where date >= initial_date
            limit 3
        )as s;

-- declare NOT FOUND handler
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET v_finished = 1;

set initial_date = '2013-01-01';

get_avg: LOOP

    OPEN cr;

    cr_loop: LOOP

        FETCH cr INTO v_avg;

        IF v_finished = 1 THEN 
            LEAVE cr_loop;
        END IF;

        insert into result values (v_avg);

    END LOOP cr_loop;

    CLOSE cr;

    #I've to change this line... the table does not have all days
    set v_dt_ini = date_add(v_dt_ini,interval 1 DAY);
    #But the problem it's not the line yet...
    set v_finished = 0;

    if v_dt_ini > '2013-05-30' then
        leave get_avg;
    end if;

END LOOP get_avg;

end$$
```

On the code I have fixed N as 3
The problem is that when I call the procedure... it calculates the 1st average of 3 records... and when performing the cursor again... it returns the same value... the 3 first records... and it's not what I need...

The cursor is not changing the result :/

Comment: Are the rows sorted by any means? I.e. is the date guaranteed to allways increase, or is there another AUTO_INCREMENT column? This would make the problem trivial!

Comment: Yes, it has an id and the date has an unique index...
On this case only the date guarantee...

When i make this search

select avg(i) from  (
        select t.info i
           from test t
          where date >= '2013-01-01'
          limit 3
        )as s;
It retuns me the right average of 3 values that begin on date 01/01/2013...

And it works for all date that i put on the code...

So I use the code as a CURSOR.. with a variable INITIAL_DATE that I incremente on the external loop...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fd2ff/16/0)

```
SELECT date,info,(select avg(info) from
                  (select date,info,@row1:=@row1+1 as row
                   from test,(SELECT @row1:=0)r
                   order by date desc
                  )wrn1
                  where wrn1.row between wrn2.start and wrn2.end)as avg,
       start,end

FROM
    (select date,info,@row:=@row+1 as row,(@row - 2) as start,@row as end
     from test,(SELECT @row:=0)r
     order by date desc
    )wrn2
WHERE start > 0
ORDER BY date asc
```

this will return

```
        DATE                   INFO     AVG       START     END
January, 01 2013 00:00:00+0000     210  212.3333    3        5
January, 02 2013 00:00:00+0000     213  208         2        4
January, 03 2013 00:00:00+0000     214  201         1        3
```

Comment: I did it with reverse order, you can play around with the order by date `asc` or `desc` in the queries for `wrn1` and `wrn2`, just so long as they match the same order they should work.

Comment: how can I convert this for 10 values average? @TinTran

Comment: @TinTran I managed to get the value of first 10 by changing `@row -2` to `@row -9` but I don't want to start from 2nd row for the next 10 values. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a correlated subquery for this.  If you want up to `n` days including and after the current date, then this will work:

```
select date, info,
       (select avg(t2.info)
        from test t2
        where datediff(t.date, t2.date) < n and
              t2.date >= t.date
       ) as avginfo
from test t;
```

If you want `n` records including and after the current one, then the following idea would work:

```
select date, info,
       (select avg(info)
        from (select t2.*
              from test t2
              where t2.date >= t.date
              order by t2.date
              limit n
             ) t3
       ) as avginfo
from test t;
```

However, this generates an error in MySQL, and I'm not sure how to work around it (the double nested query can no longer recognize the correlation to the outer query).  The following version does work as shown [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e9a0ac/17):

```
select t.date, t.info, avg(t3.info)
from (select date, info,
             (select t2.date
              from test t2
              where t2.date >= t.date
              order by t2.date
              limit 1 offset 2
             ) as date3
      from test t
     ) t left outer join
     test t3
     on t3.date between t.date and t.date3
group by t.date, t.info;
```

Comment: the first one works... but not with expected values...
It returns 205.20 instead 212.3333 and the others days on the same way :/

I tried the second.. but has compilation errors... mysql don't know t.date on the subquerie on that way... at least that is the error that MySQL brings to me :/

Comment: @arthur . . . I fixed the problem with the first one (it was getting `n+1` records).  The second is a bug in MySQL (as far as I'm concerned).  I'm not sure what the work-around is.

Comment: but... on the 5 examples that i mentioned... the average in groups of 3... i'd have only 3 returns...
I wouldn't have the same number of records...

The first value that I need is the average of the exactly 3 info's
The second average is the average of the following info records: 2nd, 3rd and 4th
The third average is the average of the 3rd, 4th and 5th values... and so on... until it has 3 values to calculate a new average

Comment: @arthur . . . Assuming the date field is incremented by one day at a time, then the first query will do that.

Comment: @arthur . . . I even noticed that your input data is missing a date.  The last version in the answer should work.

Answer (score 0):

In response to the comment about being ordered - the trick is sorting:

New values: Use a trigger - `AFTER INSERT` trigger on original table needs to select the avg of last N values ( `SELECT AVG(valuecolumn) FROM table WHERE datecolumn <= NEW.datecolumn ORDER BY datecolumn DESC LIMIT N` ) and insert it into the averages table.

Existing values: Run this front to back and use `SELECT AVG(valuecolumn) FROM table WHERE datecolumn <= NEW.datecolumn ORDER BY datecolumn ASC LIMIT M,N` with M going from 0..count-2

Comment: sorry dude... but I've kind 10 years of info... and I'll try for N=3, N=4, N=5.... and so on...

I don't think put the trigger and povoating each time that I want to try something is a good thing... beside it could work, it'd cost a lot of performance to do an average of information.